# [Facebook][Canvas] Extract original request method

Tags: ruby, facebook, rack, facebook-canvas, rack-middleware

**Short version**

Is it somehow possible to get the original request method out of the `POST` request that Facebook is performing to my web application?

**Long version**

I want to make my current web applications Facebook canvas frame compatible at the lowest level.

*About Facebook Canvas*

> Apps on Facebook are web pages loaded into a Canvas frame ..
>   When a user loads your Canvas app on Facebook, we load the Canvas URL within an iframe on that page. This results in your app being displayed within the standard Facebook chrome.

I'm a *Ruby* programmer and *Rack Middleware* seems to be a reasonable solution to this problem.

*About Rack*

> Rack provides a minimal interface between webservers supporting Ruby and Ruby frameworks.

*About Rack Middleware*

> Between the server and the framework, Rack can be customized to your applications needs using middleware

Each middleware will be initialized with a object called `env` this object is some kind of Hash. It contains the key `REQUEST_METHOD` which represent a HTTP request method.

Facebook converts all request methods to `POST`. To get my application working in the Facebook Canvas context i would have to add a extra `POST` route to my application.

Instead i would like to rewrite the `env['REQUEST_METHOD']` back to the original request method.

During research i found a gem called [*rack-facebook*](https://github.com/carlosparamio/rack-facebook/blob/master/lib/rack/facebook.rb#L63).

This gem is doing exactly what i want. It extracts `['fb_sig']['request_method']` from the params and assign it to `env['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

Sadly i also found a blog entry on the facebook dev blog

> All Canvas apps must process signed_request (fb_sig will be removed)
>
> May 10, 2011 at 8:25pm

*About Facebook Signed Request*

> For certain types of apps, a signed request is passed to the app which contains some additional fields of information, even before Permissions have been requested.

I looked into the Facebook Developer Documentation and found out that request method or something similar is no longer part of the `signed_request` param.

Is it somehow possible to get the original request method out of the `POST` request that Facebook is performing to my web application?